# Windows alternative to py.test xdist for test isolation?

Tags: windows, pytest

Is there a way to run py.test tests in isolation on windows?

I am using py.test but would like some tests run in isolation (e.g., in a separate process). I saw that the xdist package does this, but it doesn't work on Windows. Sadly I must use windows.

Is there an alternative to xdist for Windows users or some other way to get test isolation in py.test on Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In fact `pytest-xdist` works on Windows. Maybe you are talking about the specific `--boxed` option which is available only on Linux but will be dropped in the next version of `xdist` if I remember well.

What level of isolation do you need?

You can check the `pytest_configure()` and `pytest_configure_node()` hooks (to be defined in your `contest.py`) which will give you more customisation option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want something like --boxed (or thought I did). That is I would like a test run as if it was run in complete isolation in its own process. That is, I don't want it to see changes to globals made by other tests.